# Two convex sets which cannot be separated by a hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $V=L^2([0,1];\mathbb{R})$, $\hspace{3pt}$ $A=\{f\in C([0,1])\mid f(0)>0\}$ and $B=\{f\in C([0,1])\mid f(0)<0\}$.

Show that these two convex, disjoint sets cannot be separated with an hyperplane (we say $A$ and $B$ can be separated by an hyperplane if there exists $\phi \in V' \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\phi(a)\leq \phi (b) \quad \forall a \in A \quad \forall b \in B$)

What I did: every functional on $V$ is a $L^2$ function which acts by integration, so I tried to show that every function of that sort encounters some problems, but I couldn't manage to formalize it.

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you show your own work on the problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an _isolated_ problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) (same link as above comment) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you show that both $A$ and $B$ are dense in $L^2$?

Comment: Well I know $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ is dense, and I'd say that choosing a particular value at a point (so it is measure zero) wouldn't be a problem, I guess?

Comment: To say that $C[0,1]$ is dense is not the same as saying that $A$ is dense.

Comment: @copper.hat.    Are you claiming $A$ and $B$ are equal as subsets of $L^2$?  I believe they  are disjoint.

Comment: @copper.hat. I maintain that the two sets you described above are disjoint.

Comment: @Ruy The value of an element of $L^2$ at a particular point is not defined.

Comment: @copper.hat.  If $\xi$ is the $L^2$ class of the function $f\equiv 1$, how would you write it as $\xi=[g]$, with $g$ in $B$?

Comment: @Ruy Uurg, you are right. Deleting egregiously wrong comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma 1**.  For every $\varepsilon >0$, and every $M\in {\mathbb R}$, there exists some $f\in C([0, 1])$, such that
$\|f\|_2<\varepsilon $, and $f(0)=M$.

*Proof*.  Defining
$$
  f(x)
  = \left\{\matrix{
    M(1-x/\delta ), & \text{if } 0\leq x<\delta ,\hfill\cr
    0, & \text{if } \delta \leq x\leq 1,
    }\right.
  $$
and choosing $\delta $ small enough, gives the desired function.  QED

**Lemma 2**.  $A$ in dense in $L^2([0, 1])$.

*Proof*.  Given any $\xi $ in $L^2([0, 1])$, and given $\varepsilon >0$, use the fact that $C([0,1])$ is dense to pick a
continuous function $g$ with $\|\xi -g\|_2<\varepsilon /2$.  Next use Lemma (1) to find some $f\in C([0, 1])$, such that
$\|f\|_2<\varepsilon/2 $, and $f(0)=-g(0)+1$.

Setting $g'=g+f$, we then have that
$$
  g'(0) = g(0) + f(0) = 1,
  $$
so $g'$ lies in $A$.  Furthermore
$$
  \|\xi -g'\|_2 = \|\xi -g-f\|_2 \leq \|\xi -g\|_2 + \|f\|_2 < \varepsilon ,
  $$
proving that $A$ is dense in $L^2([0, 1])$.  QED

---

OK, now back to the question.

Suppose by contradiction that there is a nonzero $\phi$ such that $\phi (a)\leq \phi (b)$, for every $a$ in $A$, and
every $b$ in $B$.  Then, fixing some $b$ in $B$, the above inequality implies that
$$
  \phi (\xi )\leq \phi (b), \quad\forall \xi \in L^2([0, 1]),
  $$
by Lemma (2) and the fact that $\phi $ is continuous.

However, a nonzero linear functional is never bounded above, so this says that $\phi =0$, a contradiction.

---

PS: If we are allowed to choose $\phi $ in the algebraic dual of $L^2([0, 1])$, that is, if we do not insist on the
continuity of $\phi $, it is possible to separate $A$ and $B$.  In fact, consider the linear functional
$$
  \phi _0:f\in C([0, 1])\mapsto f(0)\in {\mathbb R},
  $$
(which is not continuous for the 2-norm) and let $\phi $ be any (necessarily discontinuous) extension of $\phi _0$ to
$L^2([0, 1])$.  Then clearly $\phi $ separates $A$ and $B$.